# Stack Overflow downloadable CV did not include picture and certificates

Tags: discussion, developer-story

I just downloaded my CV from this page, but it only contains my work experience and some other basic info. Certificates and pictures are not included. Why is this is so?

Comment: thank you S.L. Barth for your editing of my question?

Comment: What pictures?  Can you link your cv here?

Comment: by picture i mean profile photo of the user who downloads cv

Comment: I dont think that is a good idea at all.

Comment: For me it is better to include at least certificates that are updated in our profile.Any ways Thank you.

Comment: Certificates I can see yes - but profile pictures on a cv is usually not needed.

Comment: @JonH it depends on a country. Afaik in Russia CVs are typically expected to include photos and other personal information (like birthday).